# App crash when successfully passing data

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

I have a simple app. A table view passing user information from 1 view controller to another. It successfully prints out my user object and I can see the data in the console, however when I go to extract the data from the object into my view it does not display

```
@IBOutlet weak var chatPartnerLabel: UILabel!

var user: User? {
    didSet {
        print(user) //This prints out all information fine
        chatPartnerLabel.text = user?.firstName //This crashes the app because chatPartnerLabel.text is nil
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    chatPartnerLabel.text = user?.firstName //This comes up as nil 
}
```

I have also tried hardcoding the label to see if it works properly

```
chatPartnerLabel.text = "My text" //Changes the label to My Text
```

I have also tried putting `user?.firstName` in viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear both display an empty label.

As you can see in the console my user is there with data. The crash I get when attempting to set is coming up as nil

[image]

What am I doing wrong to successfully change my chatPartnerLabel to either the name or firstname?

Comment: check your IBOutlet connection with storyboard

Comment: write crash log here

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil the IBConnection is fine because I can write text and it updates correct just not with my user.

Comment: @Vyacheslav when the app crashes it says "Error unwrapping optional NIL" which I am assuming is because I am trying to set the text too early?

Comment: try setting the text in main queue from your `didSet`. Something like: `DispatchQueue.main.async { chatPartnerLabel?.text = user?.firstName }`

Comment: that prevents that crash now but still doesnt display my user data. Its so weird to me because I can literally see it printed in the console and printing the value works fine as well print(user?.firstName) returns the correct data but doesnt return the data into my label

Comment: @user934902 , please, write full callstack. You have cut them

Comment: If you are performing a `segue` and passing the data to the `destinationViewController` using `prepareForSegue`. You'll have to drop the `didSet` property observer because the `chatPartnerLabel` isn't loaded and linked to the outlet at that time. You must assign the label in your `viewDidLoad` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {
    var firstName = "fn"
}


///uiviewcontroller:


@IBOutlet weak var chatPartnerLabel: UILabel!
var user: User? {
        didSet {
            print(user) //This prints out all information fine
            chatPartnerLabel.text = user?.firstName //This crashes the app
        }
    }
```

both:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        user = User()
```

and:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        chatPartnerLabel.text = user?.firstName
```

**work! I've tested!**

We need more information and correct callstack. May be `chatPartnerLabel`is nil while unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

if you are setting `user` in segue or before pushing/presenting controller, it will crash, because label is not instantiated yet. That's why you have to rewrite your code to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var chatPartnerLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        print(user?.firstName) // just for check
        chatPartnerLabel.text = user?.firstName
    }
}

var user: User? {
    didSet {
        print(user) //This prints out all information fine
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works **Swift 3**. I added a Boolean control to know when viewDidLoad is called.

```
var user: (firstName : String, lastName : String, controlView : Bool)? {
    didSet {

        if (self.user?.controlView)! {

        print(user!)
        chatPartnerLabel.text = user?.firstName
        }

    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   user?.controlView = true
 }
```